# Maven : Infer dependencies

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-plugin, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a local repository where I have 10 projects say : A1, A2, A3 .. A10.

A4 has dependency over some projects. Is there a tool to infer the dependency order for A4 without building the dependents.

I tried mvn dependency: tree. But it shows the tree when all the dependent projects have been build.

Comment: What "dependency order" are you interested in? Could you give more information? Maybe you could also add a paragraph about the motivation because there might be a different approach you have not thought about yet.

Comment: @JFMeier
Scenario : A4 project has transitive dependencies.

A4 has pom.xml which has a dependency tag of project A7
A7 has pom.xml which has a dependency tag of project A9

Intention : For a given maven project, Is it possible to infer the order of transitive dependencies?

Comment: @JFMeier  : For this scenario, one possibility is to manually check for all poms (10  projects) and infer a build order.

I am looking for a tool which can automate this task.

Comment: A4 project has transitive dependencies. A4 has pom.xml which has a dependency tag of project A7. Likewise, A7 has pom.xml which has a dependency tag of project A9 Intention : For a given maven project, Is it possible to infer the order of transitive dependencies? 

For this scenario, one possibility is to manually check for all poms (10 projects) and infer a build order. I am looking for a tool which can automate this task

Motivation : I want to automate building of all the transitive dependencies. When I try to build A4, all the transitive dependencies should automatically build first.

Answer (score 0):

If A1,A2, ... A10 are modules of the same multi-module project, you get your desired feature for free: Building the multi-module project will automatically sort the modules into the correct order.

If your projects are tightly coupled, a multi-module project is the right choice. But you loose the freedom of building the projects separately.

I heard that Jenkins gives you the possibility to build dependencies automatically, but I know no details. It may be worth looking into that.

Comment: All these are separate projects residing in one local repository. It is not a multi-module project. Upon exploring further, I got to know that Netbeans does provide an option to 'Build with dependencies'. I use eclipse which does not have this option.  

The action mapped to "Build with Dependencies" builds the project using the Reactor plugin. When you build a project using the Reactor plugin, the dependencies of the sub-projects are built before the containing project is built.

Comment: I could not find how it is possible through mvn reactor (command-line). But it works in netbeans, even for projects which are loosely coupled. 

And, yes, thanks for the suggestions. I will explore jenkins.

Comment: Maybe its worth thinking about a multi-module project.